# unsymmetrical pitch change

Tags: pitch, controller

I want to assign unsymmetrical pitch change to my controller, let's say when I move the pitch controller to raise the pitch , it raise the pitch up to +2 semitones but when I move it to lower the pitch it lower the pitch down to -12 semitone

I want to do this in logic pro x, please give me a clue

thanks you all in advance

Comment: I don't know where to start, I tried MIDI Transform, but Don't exactly how to use it

Comment: which instruments did you try to edit? in exs24 its possible some where in the layers and zones

Comment: @mahaltertin , Thank you buddy, is possible for you to give me more detail about this? I don't use exs24 now but if it works I will switch on it. I just didn't get exactly what should I do